# Ошибка Angular: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular2

Пытался применить `ngModel`, но выдает ошибку. Вот код шаблона:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addCar()" >Добавить машину</button>
<p>{{ addCarStatus }}</p>
<hr>

<app-car></app-car>
<app-car></app-car>

<hr>

<input type="text" class="form-control" #myinpt (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp(myinpt.value)" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inputText">
<p>{{ inputText }}</p>
```

Вот код компонента:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cars.component.css']
})
export class CarsComponent {
  addCarStatus = '';
  inputText = 'Default Text';

  addCar() {
    this.addCarStatus = 'Машина добавлена';
  }

  onKeyUp(value) {
    this.inputText = value;
  }
}
```

И вот такая ошибка:

```
Error:(11, 41) Angular: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю причина в том, что не подключен `FormsModule` в вашем модуле, в котором объявлена компонента

Comment: Да, действительно проблема была в этом, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

**Забыли закрыть тег, исправьте на:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" #myinpt (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp(myinpt.value)"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inputText"/>
```

Comment: Тэг можно и не закрывать и ошибкой это не будет